# Is that possible to style a popup window through css file?

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I have searched the site, but, unfortunately, could not find the appropriate answer and decided to post the questions.

I have a small project with a couple of pages. I have a `css` file to style their content.
The content should be displayed in a popup on `window.open` that another party will open. I just need to test, how my content looks in a popup window, before deploying the pages.

Currently, I created a test page with links and testing using "javascript:window.open('mypage.htm', 'content')" to test it. I gave it some width and height to accommodate my content's dimensions. But, since, another party can control the dimensions of the pop up after deployment, I want to make sure that my content will fit perfectly in it. Is that possible to do it?

This is the part of html of one of the pages I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.name = 'content';
</script> 
<body>
  <div id="wrapper"> 
    <div class="mainImg"><img alt="" src="images/InfoSearchA.jpg"/>
    </div>
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1 class="txtName">Header</h1>
        </header>
        <p class="txtDesc">Some description</p>
      </article>
      <div class="frame">
         <div class="iframe">
             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
           document.write("<iframe id=\"frame\" src=\"someIframeContent.html</iframe>");
             </script>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="privacyterms"><a class="terms" href="privacynotes.htm"     onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank'); return false;">Privacy</a> <span class="separator"> |</span> <a class="terms" href="terms.htm" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank'); return false;">Terms</a></div>
      <div class="footerImg"><img alt="" src="images/footer.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="footerText">Footer.<br/>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is my `css` file:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Light';
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'),
         url('fonts/OpenSans-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'),
         url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}

html
{
 overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
}

body 
{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    line-height:1;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-left:1px;
    margin-right:1px;
}

h1
{
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

article
{
    color: #000000;    
}

article h1
{
    color: #0140be;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Light';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.txtName
{
    margin-left: 18px;    
}

.frame iframe
{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
 text-align:center;   
}

.frame
{
   padding-top: 5px; 
   margin-left: 10px;
}   

article p.txtDesc
{
    line-height:1.6;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    font-weight:normal;      
}

.footer
{
    margin-top:1px;
    width:855px;
}

.mainImg
{
    height:395px;
    width:875px;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:20px;  
}

.footerText
{
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin-left:1px;        
}

.footerImg
{
    width:800px;
    padding-left:7px;
    margin-left:1px;    
}

#wrapper
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:875px;
}

.privacyterms
{
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-left:12px;
    margin-left:5px;      
}

.terms
{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: Light;
    color: #0140be;
}

.separator
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #0140be;
    font-weight: 300; 
}
```

Comment: Styling the iframe doesn't have an effect on the document inside the iframe. You need to put the CSS into the document that gets loaded into the iframe.

Comment: The question is not clear. The page in the new window can load CSS just like any other page.

Comment: you can make your page responsive. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: I'm not worried about iframe. I'm worried about the content of a pop up window in side of `<div>' tags with `id` = wrapper and `class` = mainImg such as  The iframe's content will be loaded from another domain anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @Pointy, I'm trying to make it as clear as possible. I just need to know if I can control how my content will fit into a pop up page if I cannot set the pop up width and height and that may be set by someone else. Thank you

Comment: If the content is loaded from another domain, there's nothing you can do. It's the responsibility of whoever controls the page to make sure it looks OK for different window sizes.

Comment: @Pointy, I'm not worried about iframe` and `domain`. I'm controlling the content that will be loaded into `popup` window by someone else. They can control the size of the popup. My question was if there is any way I can style my content, so it will look ok nomatter what width and height for a popup was provided. Thx

Comment: OK: yes you can style content in a window; it's just content in a window, so you'd style it just like any other content. Users of desktop browsers can *always* resize their windows.